# jquery - padding to match height of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, padding, jquery-masonry

I have a situation where I need a DIV to have padding-bottom which is equal to the height of another DIV, can anyone help me with how to do this with JQuery?

(The reason being - I am using the Masonry JQuery plug in, which has a #container div which resizes the width to match the total width of all the masonry 'bricks' inside it.
I also have a slider inside that #container DIV which resizes with the #container DIV when the browser window is resized.
The problem is, the masonry plug in sets the HEIGHT of the #container DIV to match the total height of the masonry 'bricks' inside, but doesn't take into account the slider so the #container div isn't high enough to contain everything. - this is fixed if I add 'padding-bottom' to the container DIV to match the height of the #slider-wrap, however, when the window is resized smaller, the padding-bottom is the too much.)

Structure (basic):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="slider-wrap"></div>
    <div id="masonry-wrap"></div>
</div><!-- END container -->
```

I hope I have explained this properly for someone to understand and help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `padding-top` property via `css` using `jQuery`:
jQuery:

```
$("#div1").css({"padding-top": $("#anotherdiv").height() });
```

With HTML something like this:

```
<div id="div1" height="400px;">

</div>

<div id="anotherdiv">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Evan! Can I just ask, I have got this to work with your code:

<script>
 $ (document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#container").css({"padding-bottom": $("#slider-wrap").height() });

 });
</script>

However, it does not change when the window is resized, is that because I am using '$ (document).ready(function() {'?

PS - I changed it to 'padding-bottom', I put 'padding-top' by accident.

Comment: @PeteKingston Yes, you would need to use `$(window).resize(function() { /* code here */ });`